# How to translate messages in form Symfony 5.2

Tags: forms, symfony, translate

How I can set translate in FormType in Symfony 5.2 for messages ? I have validators.fr.yaml file, but i don't know how to set it

```
->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => self::MIN_LENGTH,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        'max' => self::MAX_LENGTH,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
```

and this

```
onsubmit="return confirm({{"are you sure?"}})
```

on form.index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony form type handle translation for you.

Add your translation keys to `validators.fr.yaml`

Example:

```
#validators.fr.yaml
form.password.required: Le mot de passe est obligatoire
```

Then use your translation key in your form for your constraints

```
new NotBlank([
    'message' => 'form.password.required',
])
```

You could do the same thing for all constraints and fields label inside form types.